# Can't make google maps nearby function work with callback

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, callback, angular-google-maps

So, I'm having to update some TypeScript codes written previously using setTimeout instead of Callbacks, the problem is that I can't make it work properly.

The function using settimeouts is working, so there is no reason to be configuration related (libraries=places etc). Plus, I can see in the logs that it is actually working, but my map is plain gray.

```
map_initialize(callback) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {      

      this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      this.localizacaoAtual = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: this.localizacaoAtual
      }

      if (this.origem == "atual") {
        this.origem = this.localizacaoAtual;
      }

      callback({ mapOptions: mapOptions })
    });
  }
```

Now Im gonna call the function initialize

```
if (this.origem != null && this.destino != null) {

        this.map_initialize((callback) => {

          if (this.tipoMapa == "rota") {
            this.map_calcRoute(callback);

          } else if (this.tipoMapa == "radius") {

            this.map_radius(callback);
          }
        });
    }
```

The first function being called on if, is the route map, which is actually working. But if I change the 'this.tipoMapa' value to 'radius', it won't load.

```
map_radius(mapOptions: any) {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
    let start = this.origem;
    let end = this.destino;

      this.request = {
        location: start,
        radius: '1500',
        name: ['something here']
      }

    service.nearbySearch(this.request, (results, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var stepDisplay: any = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          this.createMarker(results[i], stepDisplay);
        }
      }
        this.entrada = { mensagem: status, origem: this.origem, destino: this.destino, instrucoes: this.instrucoes };
        this.conversationService.sendMessage(this.entrada, this.context).subscribe(
          data => {
            this.conv_tratarRetorno(data);
          }, error => { }
        )
    });
  };
```

And then I have my createMarker function.

```
createMarker(place, stepdisp) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

      stepdisp.setContent(place.name);
      stepdisp.open(this.map, marker);
    });
  }
```

So basically when I call a route function, it works as indeed, but if I call a radius function it returns a gray map but with the right logs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I was calling 'mapOptions', forgot to call mapOptions.mapOptions. Silly me...